Can you change the name of Google Drive desktop instances?
I have two instances of Google Drive installed on my Mac. However, it’s seemingly not possible to rename them which means I can’t differentiate between them.
Is it possible to edit their names?


Could you explain a little more what you mean when you say it is seeming not possible to rename them? What ways have you tried to rename them so far? Please add this info to your question to help let others know what you've tried so far.
